# Saving artifacts on remote mlflow server

Tags: python, mlflow

I am trying to store `MLflow` artifacts on a remote server running `MLflow`. The server I am accessing from and server running `MLflow` are both VMs on google cloud. I can see the matrices in the `MLflow` server but not the artifacts.

I tried the flollowing methods but nonoe of them is working:

- `mlflow server     --backend-store-uri /mnt/persistent-disk     --default-artifact-root /tmp/ --host=0.0.0.0`
- mlflow server     --backend-store-uri /mnt/persistent-disk     --default-artifact-root /path/to/folder/with/mlrun --host=0.0.0.0

I also gave `rwx` permissions to the path but still getting the same error :

```
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/user/folder'
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please advise on the solution you found for this?

requesting since i am finding the artifacts are stored into the mlruns in cwd in the local server itself 
if i use mlflow.pyfunc.log_model instead of mlflow.sklearn.log_model(lr, "model")

i have created https://github.com/mlflow/mlflow/issues/1815